# Recursive sequence growth rate

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Take arbitrary $a>0$, define $\{x_n\}$ recursively by $x_0=1$ and $x_n=a(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{n-i}}{i})$. Describe the growth of $\{x_n\}$ (is it linear, exponential, etc), and determine the limit of $\sqrt[n]{x_n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

some things that I have trying: Due to the first term it seems the sequence grows similar to exponential, but I am unsure of limit because first term does not dominate. For $a=1$ the first few terms are: $b_0=1$, $b_1=1$, $b_2=\frac{3}{2}$, $b_3=\frac{7}{3}$, $b_4=3$, $b_5=\frac{157}{60}$

Edit: A user has shown that once we know function exponential, we can approximate answer. However, how can we rigorously prove its exponential?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to even approach this problem.

Comment: see [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Fine I will edit in some small rpgoress

Comment: i have edit in some progress

Comment: Hint: consider $x_n - x_{n-1}$ to find a simpler recursion relation which you can possibly solve.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the recursion relation as $x(n) = a \sum_{i=1}^{n} x(i-1)/i$. Hence my  previous comment and the answer (which I have just deleted) are obsolete.

Comment: The mix of $i$ and $n-i$ in the sum strongly suggests looking at a generating function approach. Have you explored that avenue at all?

Comment: I am not familiar with generating functions so no I have not explored that. I will learn about it and see if I can apply. Do you see solution involving it?

Comment: I haven't worked through all the calculations but I believe I can see a pointer towards a solution that way. More context would help here — where did you come across the problem (it certainly reads like a textbook problem) and what tools are you expecting to apply to solve it?

Comment: I have found and numerically verified that limit in question is given by $L(a) := \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{1/n} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-1/a}}$. Will soon explain this in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice one, and it was tough. I provide here a conjectured answer.

I have found it with a CAS (mathematica) which gave me numerically an overview of the solution, which then could be transformed into a a conjected analytic expression which in turn was verified numerically by the CAS. A proof of the conjecture is still missing (I thank @jxia1234
for pointing this out).

The conjected answer is

$$L(a) :=\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \frac{1}{1-e^{-1/a}}\tag{1}$$

The heuristic derivation proceeds in two steps

Step 1: Numericaly solving the recursion
$$x_n = a  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x_{n-k}}{k}, x_0=1\tag{2}$$

The solution for  some values of the parameter $a$ are shown here (as lines instead of points for better visibility)

[image]

We can see that for large enough $n$ we have an exponential behaviour

$$x_n \simeq A e^{B n}\tag{3}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are numbers depending on the parameter $a$.

The quantity we are finally looking for is the $n$th root
$$L(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} A^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{B} = e^{B(a)}\tag{4}$$
notice that it is independent of $A$.

Step 2: In order to find an approximate analytic expression for $B(a)$ we insert $(3)$ into the recursion $(2)$, giving $A e^{B n} = a  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{A  e^{B (n-k)}}{k}$. Cancelling the common factors $A$ and $e^{B}$ this reads

$$1=a \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{e^{-B k}}{k}\tag{5}$$

Extending the range of $n$ to $\infty$ (here enters the approximation) this simplifies to $\frac{1}{a}= -\log(1-e^{-B})$ which can be solved for $B$ leading to the result $(1)$.

Comment: I am somewhat confused on your first step. How do you explicitly prove it has exponential behavior?

Comment: I did not prove it but the numerical results strongly suggest it. The exponential behaviour is definitely only observed for large n. Especially for a < 1 the sequence starts with decreasing values.

Comment: I understand that numerical results suggest it, but the problem requires a rigorous proof.

Comment: Numerical checks gives me confidence that the result (1) is correct. You can try it out.  I was surprised myself that the limit is given by such a simple formula. I can't do more at the moment. Maybe someone else fills the gap(s).

Comment: @jxia1234 I have reformulated my answer taking your justified comments into account.

Comment: Hello, I would like ask follow up question. Assuming function is indeed exponential, how to determine $A$, $B$?

Comment: @ jxia1234 As I said before, the sequence is NOT exponential, but it is only asymptotically so, i.e. for n>>1. Furthermore, as the calculations in my solution show A dops out and B is calculated explicitly.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'd appreciate a reason. Thank you.